# Identifying a Customized Built-In Element without an is= attribute

Tags: custom-element

In my [Chessly.github.io](https://chessly.github.io) project I use Customized Built-In IMG Elements to define SVG chesspieces:

[image]

**Question:** How can I distinguish a regular IMG from a customized IMG?

```
document.body.append(
  document.createElement("IMG", { 
    is: "white-queen"
  });
);
```

This creates a chesspiece, **but does not set the `is=` attribute**

I now explicitly set the `is=` attribute myself, but since this attribute does nothing and can be set to any value (I use `is` as an observed attribute in my Custom Element code) it is not a solid way to distinguish IMG elements from Customized IMG elements when walking the DOM.

If I promote a pawn (replace the img src)

`<img is=white-pawn/>`

with `element.setAttribute("is","white-queen")`

How can I determine the piece originally was the white pawn?
It still is a white-pawn in the Custom Elements registry.

Am I overlooking something?

Simplified code (with basic SVG shape) in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dannye/k0va2j76/

## Update: Code (based on correct answer below)

```
let isExtendedElement = x => 
      Object.getPrototypeOf(x).__proto__.constructor.name !== 'HTMLElement';
```

**note!** This does NOT catch **Autonomous** Custom Elements!

maybe better:

```
let isBaseElement = x =>
    Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(x)).__proto__.constructor.name=='Element';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think adding explicitly the `is` attribute is the best solution for now.

Else you'll have to deal with the class reference. In your case:

```
yourElement.constructor === customElements.get( 'circle-image' )
yourElement.constructor === CircleImage //if it's the named class
```

This supposes that you know the name of the custom elements you want to check.

Else you'll have to go through the protoype chain:

*CircleImage --> HTMLImageElement --> HTMLElement --> Element --> Node*

If `HTMLElement` is only the father, it's a built-in element.
If `HTMLElement` is the grandfather (or grand-grand...), it's probably an extended build-in element.

**update**

If you use a named class you can also retrieve its name:

```
elem.constructor.name
```